# How to use where() condition with min() in ActiveQuery

Tags: yii2

I am modifying this query to Yii2 `ActiveRecord`.

```
$query = "SELECT min(sorting_value) as sorting_value FROM table WHERE sorting_value>'$variable'"
```

As far I have done this:

```
$queryValue = Mymodel::find()->min('sorting_value')->where(['sorting_value' > $sort1]);
```

And it is showing this error:

> Call to a member function where() on a non-object

How can I solve this issue. I can't use where condition with `min()` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [`min()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#min()-detail) will not return ActiveQuery object, you should simply use `where()` before :

```
$queryValue = Mymodel::find()->where(['>', 'sorting_value', $sort1])->min('sorting_value');
```

Comment: I have used 
`$queryValue = Mymodel::find()->select('sorting_value')->where('sorting_value' > ':sort1', [':sort1' => $sort1])->min('sorting_value');`
But now I am getting this error:
**Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 0.  SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.
The SQL being executed was: SELECT MIN(sorting_value) FROM [visit_planner] WHERE 1' **

Comment: @soju Can you state how to show the id of sorted value using min()?